# How can add checkbox to the datatables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to put check box to the data table ,and the output is coming from Json array ,and displaying these array elements in html table using javascript.

and I want to add a checkbox to each and every row so that it can be easy to edit,delete.

**HTML Code is:**

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped num-right-alignct">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th  style="text-align: center;">Ad Headline</th>
            <th  style="text-align: center;">Ad ID</th>
            <th  style="text-align: center;">Ad Description 1</th>
            <th  style="text-align: center;">Ad Description 2</th>
            <th  style="text-align: center;">URL Appeared</th>
            <th  style="text-align: center;">Clicks</th>
            <th  style="text-align: center;">CPC</th>
            <th  style="text-align: center;">Conversions</th>
            <th  style="text-align: center;">CTR %</th>
            <th  style="text-align: center;">Impressions</th>
            <th  style="text-align: center;">Avg Pos</th>
            <th  style="text-align: center;">Cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS code:**

```
$("#groupid").change(function(){
var oTable = $('#example1').dataTable();
var grpvalue=$('#groupid').val();
                $.ajax({
                type:"post", 
                dataType : 'json',
                url:"pages/ads.php", 
                data:"adgroup="+grpvalue, 
                success: function(s) {
                oTable.fnClearTable();
                for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                    oTable.fnAddData([          
                        s[i]['hea']["0"],
                        s[i]['id']["0"],
                        s[i]['desc']["0"],
                        s[i]['desc2']["0"],
                        s[i]['url']["0"],
                        s[i]['cli']["0"],
                        s[i]['cpc']["0"],
                        s[i]['con']["0"],
                        s[i]['ctr']["0"],
                        s[i]['imp']["0"],

                        s[i]['ap']["0"],
                        s[i]['cost']["0"]
                        ]);
                        }
                        }
            });
});
```

And html table data is dynamic and I want to add a checkbox to each and every row.please let me know the procedure to do this.

Comment: use `render:fuunction()` in `columns` definitions. See docs

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer,so that I can understand

Comment: Read the documentation

Comment: Some years later: Now, there is a great plugin, works with serverside to, incl. selectall an more: https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to show you how I solved my problem. This may help you. My Datatable version is : DataTables 1.10.0

Html Code:

```
    <table  id="table_id">
    <thead ">
        <tr>
        <th>STM Name</th>
        <th>Physical Termination Prefix</th>
        <th>Media gateway Name</th>
        <th>Primary Megaco IP</th>
        <th>Primary Megaco Port</th>
        <th>Administrative Status</th>
        <th>Operational Status</th>
        <th>Select <input value="-1"   type="checkbox"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        <!--Table will generate here.-->

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Pass response like this from the server:

```
{"aaData":[{"id":1,"name":"stm1","physicalTerminationPrefix":"pre","mediagatewayName":"mgw1","primaryMegacoIp":"192.19.0.1","primaryMegacoPort":4444,"actionStatus":1,"checkbox":"\u003cinput  type\u003d\u0027checkbox\u0027 value\u003d\u00271\u0027 /\u003e","idLink":"\u003ca href\u003d\u0027#\u0027 id\u003d\u00271\u0027\u003e1\u003c/a\u003e","nameLink":"\u003ca href\u003d\u0027#\u0027 id\u003d\u00271\u0027\u003estm1\u003c/a\u003e","administrativeStatus":"FRESH_ENTRY","operationalStatus":-1,"operationalStatusStr":"ACTIVE"}]}
```

configure your js like this:

```
    var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable({
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [7]}
                ],
                "info": false,
                "bStateSave": true,
                "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],
                pagingType: "simple",
                "oLanguage": {
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sNext": '&gt',
                        "sLast": '&raquo',
                        "sFirst": '&laquo',
                        "sPrevious": '&lt'
                    },
                    "sEmptyTable": "No STM is Found !!!"
                },
                "aoColumns": [
                    //{"mData": "idLink"},
                    {"mData": "nameLink"},
                    {"mData": "physicalTerminationPrefix"},
                    {"mData": "mediagatewayName"},
                    {"mData": "primaryMegacoIp"},
                    {"mData": "primaryMegacoPort"},
                    {"mData": "administrativeStatus"},
                    {"mData": "operationalStatusStr"},
                    {"mData": "checkbox"}],
                "bProcessing ": true,
                "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        "dataType": 'json',
                        "type": "POST",
                        "url": sSource,
                        "data": 'data',
                        "success": function (data) {

                            oTable.fnClearTable();
                            if (data.aaData.length != 0)
                            {
                                oTable.fnAddData(data.aaData);
                                oTable.fnDraw();
                            }

                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("Error Code: " + jqXHR.status + ", Type:" + textStatus + ", Message: " + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

and Prepare your **checkbox** column like this in the server:

```
 var checkbox ="<input  type='checkbox' value='1' />";
```

Here is my sample Output:
[image]

Comment: "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) what are these parameters ?

Comment: sSource is the ajax URL, fnCallback is the ajax callback Function and aoData is array of Object(Data) to pass this ajax call

Comment: you need call this function **oTable.fnReloadAjax()** to trigger the fnServerData. you can google to know  **fnReloadAjax**

Comment: What is meant by lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],

Comment: skip these. It was necessary for my project to change  dropdown pagination. such as 5 pages per pages. just focus on these "{"mData": "checkbox"}]," under ** "aoColumns":** and send checkbox html from the server as json response.

Comment: where to get the aoData

Comment: I am newbie to js that's why I don't understand anything that is written in the js

Comment: skip this too you don't need it. Please have look on datatables website.

Answer (score 0):

Define them for column definitions -

```
var oDataTable = j('#yourtableid').dataTable( {
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": "requestedage.php",
"aoColumns": [ 
              {"mData" : "ID"},
              {
                "mData": "Date",
                "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                  return '<input type="checkbox" name="modifiedname" id="modifiedname"> Label';
                },
              }
            ],
 ..... //rest of the setting
```

`data` `type` `full` are the parameters passed to the function. See the docs to know about more about the passed arguments.

Comment: depends on version of plugin, after 1.10 API changed

Comment: I don't where to place the code actually ,I am a newbie to js and ajax.

Comment: @charlietfl when i worked on this it was latest. dint know about the current version. :)

Comment: Can you please provide the documentation link ,so that I can view

Comment: its in the previous comments.

Comment: ok,what are these parameters to pass to following function "mRender": function ( data, type, full )